# ASP.NET MVC Core Deployment via Visual Studio does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, ftp, asp.net-core-mvc

I am sorry to ask a question which doesn't have a specific problem, but I would be more than grateful if you could point the problem. (I can always provide other parts of my code which would be relevant to my question)

I am using Visual Studio to create my web application with ASP.NET MVC Core. All is good with the project and I can make it work on my localhost.

I bought a third party hosting service with Windows hosting (Plesk) and as far as I've asked them, they said their hosting plan supports ASP.NET Core.

For the deployment part, I've literally searched each and every source and tried various different methods but could not properly upload my files on ftp. Trying ASP.NET Core 1.0.0 version worked well and I uploaded a sample website, but since I am working with ASP.NET Core 1.1.0 now, I am unable to find a solution.

Here is what my publish profile looks like before hitting *publish* button:
[image]
[image]

I'm not really sure if I filled all the information correctly, but validation seems to work well.

And here is the log which I get after trying the publish via ftp method in visual studio:

[image]

Even though it seems to succeed, when I look at my ftp directory after this process, the files in visual studio project were never uploaded in the directory.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I came to this via Freelancer. I think the you need to check the server where it uploading your files. Since if it giving you a message on console I am sure it is uploading somewhere. Or try with a new instance if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have deploy the same on my server and it is working fine see the attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Please make sure your post is usable without any images or links. Use images to enhance your writing and links for further reference.

Comment: I don't understand how you deployed the same on your server? My source code should be pretty different from that of yours